# How properties are cached in memory by Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

As we know index on property make it possible to find some node/relationship in O(log n) time.

However, I consider what happen if Neo4j load data into memory? It is known that Neo4j load chunks (pages) of storage file into memory. In this case I have some doubt:

How fast Neo4j is able to find node by some property which is indexed ? After all, index is not loaded into memory. Can someone try to explain it?

On the one hand we have nodes and their properties in memeory (cached), on the other hand we have index on disk.  Maybe better way is to do fullscan (don't touch index!) in memory?

Comment: Why are you saying that indexes are not in memory ? They should !

Comment: Could explain more about it ?